# Anybody recognise this connector on an LED module?

Tags: led, identification

I purchased a handful of these Luxeon K16 LED arrays a while back, they are surplus units from a Toshiba DLP projector if I'm not mistaken. They have solder pads onboard, but also feature a Molex-type of connector as well:

[image: Luxeon K16 LED module]

[Link to product on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5x-45W-LUXEON-Rebel-ES-Royal-Blue-16up-450nm-High-Power-Led-Emitter-/262285567829)

At first I thought this may be a 3 pin Molex EZ picomate, but the side latching is different, and it is not the same connector style. I have been having great difficulty figuring out what connector will fit these boards, as I would rather use a plug-in solution in powering these boards.

Several of the sellers of these do not have any useful information (thoroughly unsurprising!) on these, other than that they are surplus.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It does look a lot like what you suggest. Something like [this](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoezmate&channel=PRODUCTS&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&utm_source=dpb&utm_medium=lit&utm_campaign=general&WT.mc_id=A03322) seems very close, indeed.

Comment: Likely to be for an onboard themistor to monitor the LED temperature.

Comment: Well, dug through my LED stash to compare, here is one of the modules, compared to the Bridgelux Vero using the aforementioned EZ picomate harness, and they are definitely different in the way that they latch.

http://i67.tinypic.com/4l50mr.jpg

http://i64.tinypic.com/x3j1c6.jpg